# Move envelopes Feature in Docusign

Tags: docusignapi

Problem: Envelopes moved to recycle bin are been showing up in the report even after 2 days. We are using EnvelopesApi.listStatusChanges to get the envelope status

Description:

We are using move envelopes feature to move the envelopes to the recycle bin and eventually after 1 day the envelope being moved is removed from the account and we can no longer see the envelope in any of the folders. But interestingly the envelope that's been moved is shown up when we made an API call EnvelopesApi.listStatusChange and even it's been showing up when we made the Rest call get envelope status /accounts/{accountId}/envelopes

Question

Is there a way to identify such kinds of envelopes that have been moved to recycle bin and no longer been available in any of the folders but shown up through the API Calls?. Looking to see if we can identify such kind of envelopes with any parameters that have been returned from any of the API calls

Answer (score 1):

You should call below URI, as documented [here](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Folders/Folders/list/):

```
GET /v2/accounts/{accountId}/folders
```

to know all the folders you have access to, this will also return the recyclebin folder uri, response will be like below:

```
    {
      "ownerUserName": "Sender Nae",
      "ownerEmail": "email@gmail.com",
      "ownerUserId": "87b00103-461d-487b-8928-1991dfdb8d19",
      "type": "recyclebin",
      "name": "Deleted Items",
      "uri": "/folders/2fdc7ffc-60d5-4c36-9f9a-1410c30de0eb",
      "folderId": "2fdc7ffc-60d5-4c36-9f9a-1410c30de0eb"
    }
```

Now, read folderId or uri from the response for type - recyclebin, and call below uri to know all the envelopes which have been moved to recyclebin. Details are available at [DS Docs](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Folders/Folders/listItems/)

```
GET /restapi/v2/accounts/{accountId}/folders/2fdc7ffc-60d5-4c36-9f9a-1410c30de0eb
```

Comment: Here the problem is I don't see the envelopes those are been moved to the recycle bin after 1-2 days, but they are been shown up during the API call  EnvelopesApi.listStatusChange.

Comment: whats the status of the envelope which you are not seeing neither on WEBApp nor on recyclebin

Comment: Of the scenarios that I have identified they are Voided and completed

Comment: Voided and Completed should be present in your sent folder, they will not move to recycle bin.

Comment: 1)They are not present in the sent folder or any folders 2)Are you saying that voided and completed will stay in the same folder even though we delete?.(Since move envelope through API is equivalent to delete option through the DocuSign UI)

Comment: If you have deleted the voided or completed envelopes then they will move to recyclebin, and I think there is an hourly batch job in DocuSign which will delete these envelopes from recyclebin folder as well. Even when you delete the Completed envelope from the UI's sent folder it explicitly says `Deleted envelopes remain in your Deleted bin for only a short time, after which they are removed permanently.`. It is actually removing the envelopes from the view but behind the scene envelope will always be present, and can be access using API till the time it is not purged.

Comment: Is there any api call to identify that a given envelope is deleted?

Comment: My qs is why would you delete completed, declined or voided envelopes as those are the envelopes for which DS will charge you for and should be in sent folder only? Ideally draft envelopes are put to deleted folders if you do not need draft envelopes any more.

Comment: We do testing in production after we push changes, so we do not want our business to receive the envelope info of our test cases. So we wan to identify such envelope and remove their entry from our custom report.

Comment: There is no way to find the envelopes which were deleted, but at the time of testing in PROD, you should send envelope to fixed list of test emails, then call `GET /v2/accounts/{accountId}/search_folders/{searchFolderId}?include_recipients=true`, this will return all the envelopes with the recipients emailId, then you can write logic to remove those envelopes where recipient emails are the ones which you used for testing. Hope this will resolve your issue!